# Encoding 4K 60Hz lossless from a capture card

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, lossless-compression, nvenc

Windows 10 64-bit
Ryzen 7
GTX 1080
32GB RAM

Hi all,

I'm trying to encode 4K 30/60Hz video in a lossless format from a 4K capture card and everything I've tried gives me a similar error as in the linked image, [real-time buffer too full or near too full frame dropped]

[Not mine]
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/4932401/22171307/ef5c9864-df58-11e6-8821-4b74ce3f32d0.png

This is the command I've tried most recently:

ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -video_size 3840x2160 -framerate 30 -pixel_format bgr24 -rtbufsize INT_MAX -i video="MZ0380 PCI, Analog 01 Capture" -vf fps=30 out%d.BMP

With the images dumped to a 10G RAM disk or 850 EVO. I'm doing this to skip the encoding step.

I get the same error when encoding with h265 lossless and NVENC h265 lossless.

I need the video to be lossless as it will be used to test hardware h265 encoders.

Video source is a 4K Blu-ray.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

-Alex P

Comment: Your input is 1.4 GB/s and your rtbufsize is 100M as per the log. rtbufsize expects a number (SI suffixes ok); are you sure machine constants are parsed correctly? Try an explicit value of 1G.

Comment: That image is not my own but I get the same error except its 217000000000 instead of 100000000 as per the -rtmaxbuf INT_MAX pram. I get the same error with -rtmaxbuf 2G.

Comment: Keeping a high rtbufsize, try to skip encode and output I/O to check if the latency is due to onward processing: replace `-vf fps=30 out%d.BMP` with `-f null -`

Comment: which capture card is this ? what is it's default native lossless pixel format ?

Comment: Mulvya, I tried outputting to null and got x1 performance. I then tried writing the file to a ram disk and got x0.303. Has anyone used ffmpeg to capture 4K video?